# How do I insert a value from a table into another table in the same database? And only take out the year from date?

Tags: database, oracle, date, plsql, insert

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    YEAR NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    LENGTH NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT AVGYEAR_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(YEAR))

CREATE TABLE B(
    ID1              NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL,
    DATE_DONE        DATE            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT TRIP_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (ID1),
);
```

I want to insert values into table A, but the YEAR value from Table A,I would have to take from table b and only the 'YYYY' not the whole date.

Do i do something like this

```
insert into A VALUES(YEAR value,LENGTH value)
insert into A VALUES(select TO_CHAR((DATE_DONE),'YYYY') from B, 10.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, this could be what you need.

Say you have

```
SQL> select * from B;

       ID1 DATE_DONE
---------- ---------
         1 01-JAN-19
         2 31-DEC-18
         3 01-JUN-17

SQL> select * from A;

no rows selected
```

with this

```
SQL> insert into a(year, length) select extract(year from date_done), 10 from B;

3 rows created.
```

you get:

```
SQL> select * from A;

      YEAR     LENGTH
---------- ----------
      2019         10
      2018         10
      2017         10
```

If you need a distinct, this is the way:

```
insert into a(year, length) select DISTINCT extract(year from date_done), 10 from B;
```

Comment: i try inserting but as year is a primary key i would have to use DISTINCT function i got missing parenthesis error.                                                                            insert into a(select extract(DISTINCT YEAR FROM date_done)),10 from B;

Comment: You only need to place the DISTINCT in the right place, just showed an example